# How can we play 2 videos side by side as per the resolution we provide to the output video and adjust the two input videos position

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

-> For playing two video side by side as per the output video resolution I provide :-

1. I want output video of resolution 1280x720 so for this.

a. First I have trimmed the two video using below command :-

```
ffmpeg -i input_viedo.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:20 -vf      "scale=1920:1080,pad=1920:1080:0:0:yellow" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 output_video_trimmed.mp4
```

b. Now to I want to play both the trimmed video into one output video file as per the position I provide , so for this I have tried below command which is not giving the correct output :

```
ffmpeg -i output_video_trimmed_1.mp4 -i output_trimmed_2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=634:360[pad1];[1:v]scale=640:360[pad2];[pad1]pad=1280:360:0:100[tl];[pad2]pad=1280:360:634.752:130.392[br];[tl][br]vstack,scale=1280:720[output]" -map "[output]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 1280x720 output_final_video.mp4
```

- In above command I have provide the specific width,height,top,left of the input video I want ,

But it is not giving me correct output.

--> Output I am getting by running this command is attached below :-

[Output video Image I am getting by running above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O6Ab.png)

[Actual output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z79WJ.png)

--> The issue in above command is while adding top it is not working properly , like top is not affecting the video so I want the solution for that.